# Extract metadata from custom file format and use in file manager

Tags: list, file, metadata, extract

I have been looking for a tool that allows me to scan files for metadata (I have an extensive directory full of test logs that are basically my own file format. Metadata would be "fail/pass" etc.). 
I would basically want to have a local or web-based file manager where I can basically add custom columns and manage my files based on the extracted metadata. Does anyone know what would be a good project/tool for me to build on/start with? 
I hope this is not too vague, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit? Yeah. Its vague enough to flag it though. Too many possible `good` answers.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! I will try to clarify. I have a ton of ".log" files, that I used to store test results. they all consist of multiple steps. some of them pass, some fail. I'd like something that extracts this information and enables me to sort and manage file based on metadata that was generated based on the extracted information. (instead of aperture, dpi etc. I'd want pass/fail stored as metdata)

Comment: It would be better if you'd update the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you'd update the question instead.
Look, when posting, you'd want to share your problem, not what bugs you.

Like, how did you store. Its definitely possible to sort based on their test files on the log files if theres a constant format pattern. In the .log files I hope they are like
`"a.jpg : pass ; pass ; fail"` (can't be sure though)

So, write a program that finds which have passed and which have failed. In a different folder, create a file with that file name. copy everything from source to destination in that order. This will update the timestamps and when you'll sort by date/time in any file manager in that folder, you'll see your sorted results. I advise you to write the specifications of the log file and get into work. Its certainly easy enough unless you are not using any delimiters.